# How to make list Comprehensions faster?

Tags: numpy, performance

Is there anything in general i could use to speed up nested list comprehensions ( sometimes conditional) ?

I was thinking about numpy or transposing (but how?), but there might be anything ive overseen.

Examples:

````
nextInt = 1
winPoints  = [[max(upSlice[:i])  for i in range(nextInt,len(upSlice)+1)] for upSlice in ppValues]```
````

or

```
winningRatio =[ [1 if ratioUp >ratioDown  else 0 if (ratioDown>ratioUp) else
                1 if (pointsUp>pointsDown) else 0 if (pointsDown>pointsUp) else 1   
                for ratioUp,ratioDown,pointsUp,pointsDown                  in  zip(ratioUpSlice,ratioDownSlice,pointsUpSlice,pointsDownSlice)] 
                for ratioUpSlice,ratioDownSlice,pointsUpSlice,pointsDownSlice in  zip(ratios_Up,ratios_Down, pointsUpSlices,pointsDownSlices)]
```

(all slices in the nested list do NOT have the same lenght)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `ppValues` is a 2-dimensional list of numbers?

Generally, to speed up algorithms you want to shave off any redundant calculation. For example, in your first piece of code, the `max(upSlice[:i])` part is executed (n*m) times and is executing approximately ((n^2)/2 * m) calculations where (n) is the length of the inner list and m is the length of the outer list. And the execution is calculating the max of the same slice (except wIth 1 additional element) which is a lot of unnecessary comparisons.

To speed it up, we can use dynamic programming, where we build a `slice_max` array such that the element at index `i` is the `max(upSlice[:i])`. And we can do this efficiently by utilizing past computations since the element at index `i` is equal to the max of two elements, `max(slice_max[i-1], upSlice[i])` which is only a single computation.

Here's a simple implementation of the dynamic programming version:

```
def get_slice_max(arr, start):
    result = [max(arr[:start])]
    for i in range(start, len(arr)):
        result.append(max(result[-1], arr[i]))
    return result
winPoints  = [get_slice_max(upSlice, nextInt) for upSlice in ppValues]
```

Here's a comparison:

Generating Data

```
# generate fake data
np.random.seed(42)
# the variable length of inner lists: [7270,  860, 5390, ..., 1389, 4276, 1249]
inner_sizes = np.random.randint(low=1, high=1000, size=10000)
ppValues = [np.random.randint(1000, size=i) for i in inner_sizes]
# ppValues contains 10000 lists, each having 1 to 1000 elements, each element is a number between 1 to 10000
```

Your version

```
nextInt=1
winPoints  = [[max(upSlice[:i])  for i in range(nextInt,len(upSlice)+1)] for upSlice in ppValues]

------------------
Wall time: 2min 36s
```

Simple Dynamic Programming Version

```
def get_slice_max(arr, start):
    result = [max(arr[:start])]
    for i in range(start, len(arr)):
        result.append(max(result[-1], arr[i]))
    return result
winPoints  = [get_slice_max(upSlice, nextInt) for upSlice in ppValues]

-----------------
Wall time: 1.79 s
```

You can see a major improvement from 2.5 minutes to <2 seconds.

As for the second example, you did not provide enough context to try to tackle that problem.

Comment: this is awesome thanks (thought comprehensions were always faster than loops). One thing: "nextInt" would be the point to start with, so that when nextInt==1 the first element wouldnt be used so that "result" will have one element less than the original "arr". So i dont understand the first line "result = [max(arr[:start])]".

Comment: the second code is a conditional. First we compare the two ratio values " ratioUp" and "ratioDown". If they are the same we next compare the two point values "pointsUp" and "pointsDown". If they are also the same ( which is very rare) we just set it 1 too. By these two comparison-factors i decide something similar, to a "side" which I use as a label in DataScience

Comment: Hi @Ishmael89 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: sure thats fair, im still looking for a way to speed up the second piece of code